# Postman returning not found 404 in api of .net core

Tags: api, asp.net-core, controller, postman

net core 3.1, on the post method, postman returns status 404 not found. The commented code is what I tried.

```
   [Route("api/Servicio")]
    public class ServicioController : Controller
    
            private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    
            public ServicioController(ApplicationDbContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }
    
            // POST: api/PostServicio
            //[HttpPost("api/PostServicio")]
            //[HttpPost("servicio")]
            [HttpPost("api/PostServicio/{servicio}")]
            //public async Task<ActionResult<Servicio>> PostServicio([FromBody]Servicio servicio)
            public async Task<ActionResult<Servicio>> PostServicio(Servicio servicio)
            {
                _context.Servicio.Add(servicio);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                
                return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetServicio), new { id = servicio.Id }, servicio);
            }

   // GET: api/GetServicio/5        
   [HttpGet("GetServicio/{tecnico}/{semanaDelAno}")]
   public async Task<ActionResult<Servicio>> GetServicio(string tecnico, int semanaDelAno)
   {
            var servicio = await _context.Servicio.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Tecnico == tecnico && 
              i.SemanaDelAno == semanaDelAno);

            if (servicio == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return servicio;
   }

}
```

In postman i have a body, raw, json

```
{
  "Tecnico":"Jhon",
  "ServicioRealizado":"Servicio1",
  "SemanaDelAno": 1,
  "Dia": "Lunes",
  "HoraInicial": 13.0,
  "HoraFinal": 15.0
}
```

I have this two actions, I got this code basically from the api tutorial in the documentation.

[image: Postman]

UPDATE ************************************************

```
  // POST: api/PostServicio        
        [HttpPost("PostServicio")]        
        public async Task<ActionResult<Servicio>> PostServicio([FromBody]Servicio servicio)        
        {
            _context.Servicio.Add(servicio);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            //return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetServicio), new { tecnico = servicio.Tecnico }, new { semanaDelAno = servicio.SemanaDelAno });
            return servicio;
        }
```

Now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure your request url is:`https://localhost:portNumber/api/Servicio/api/PostServicio/xxx`.xxx matches the `{servicio}`.

But actually I think it is no need add `{servicio}` to your `HttpGet` attribute.Because you post the data from body instead of route.So the `{servicio}` here is useless.Just use `[HttpPost("api/PostServicio")]` and the request url:`https://localhost:portNumber/api/Servicio/api/PostServicio`.Then post the data from body by choose raw json in postman.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#attribute-routing-with-http-verb-attributes